# How to implement search view for a ListView in android

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` that contains data from data base! I want to implement search view for this that items has searched elements should be shown! I tried more and saw examples but they was hard for me  to understand! any way? easy please!

Comment: This is too broad for SO. You need to post the code which you are having trouble with and explain what isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic should help : -

1) get the search bar on your ActionBar

2) Add a SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() to your search bar.

3) Override the onQueryTextChange() method and perform a search function on your DB against the string entered.

4) Once you have the data, pass it to the same function you used to structure your ListView in the beginning so as to form an adapter which can be set to your listview.

P.s. be better if you posted your code for us to help out. The above logic worked for me....